# Generate Signed APK using Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am pretty sure that I have checked all the possible duplicate questions and none solve my problem. I have instant run turned off, I have minfy and shrink set to false. I have cleaned. The keyfile exists and worked perfectly on a previous release of this app. I have tried running the compile with --info but it does not give me any hints as the the problem. The error is:

*Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
 Failed to read key myreleasekey from store "C:\Users\Mel\AndroidStudioProjects\tourbuilderkeystore.jks": Cannot recover key*

My build gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myguidedtours.www.tourguide"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 10
        versionName '1.10'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
//    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1"
    implementation files('libs/PdfViewer.jar')
}
```

I have been sweating over this for two days - I hope you can help.

Comment: Your error is telling you that the key `myreleasekey ` does not exist in your keystore file `tourbuilderkeystore.jks`.  Try looking inside your keystore file to see what keys are actually in there. `keytool -list -v -keystore tourbuilderkeystore.jks -storepass {keystore password}`

Comment: the GUI lets one select keys from a drop-down, once having entered the store password.

Comment: Yes thanks. The file is there and worked perfectly on a previous release of the app. All I am doing is updating the app to use a higher target SDK Version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case there's someone out there as stupid as me. The prompt for Generate a Signed APK in Android Studio, does not tell you if the passwords you supply are good or bad. I must have miss-keyed one of them, then, because I ticked the remember passwords option, it failed every time I tried to run it. There is no hint that the password may be wrong - usually when you enter a bad password you get immediate feedback.